# Get.toNamed not working from bottom sheet / different context

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I want to use Get.toNamed from a nested bottom sheet (bottom sheet called from a bottom sheet). However, it is not working. I think it's because the context is different. If I was using Navigator, `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed("/route");`  this would work. However, in my case, I must use the GetX router because the given route is taking in arguments from `Get.arguments`. Is there any workaround to make Get.toNamed work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see where the problem is without looking at you code. GetX is just a wrapper around Navigator, so both should work.

Try

```
Get.offAndToNamed<void>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that Get.arguments can read arguments even if `Navigator` was used to come to a route. So I just used `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed('/home', arguments: {'tab': 2});`